# Vue Events - Can't listen to $emit event from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having a simple issue, that I just can't figure out why it isn't working.
I have a child component "app-buttons", where i have an input field, i want to listen to, so i can filter a list based on the input value.

If i put the input in the root component where i have the list, all works good. But i want to split it up, and $emit the search input value, to the parent en then use it.

```js
// THIS IS THE COMPONENT WHERE I WAN'T TO LISTEN TO THE SEARCH INPUT

import Buttons from './app-buttons.js';
import Event from './vue-event.js';

export default Vue.component('post-item', {

 template: `
  <section class="posts flex" v-if="posts">
   <app-buttons :posts="posts"></app-buttons>

   <transition-group name="posts" tag="section" class="posts flex">
    <article class="postitem" :class="{ 'danger': !post.published }" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
     <p v-if="post.published">Post is published</p>
     <p v-else>Post is <em><strong>not</strong></em> published</p>
     <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>

     <button type="submit" @click="post.published = !post.published">Change status</button>
    </article>
   </transition-group>
  </section>
 `,

 data() {
  return {
  };
 },

 components: {
  Buttons,
 },

 props: {
  posts: Array,
  filterdList: [],
 },

 created() {
  console.log('%c Post items', 'font-weight: bold;color:blue;', 'created');
 },

 computed: {
  //filteredList() {
  // return this.posts.filter(post => {
  //  return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
  // });
  //},
 },

 methods: {
  update() {
   console.log('test');
  }
 }
});





// THIS IS THE COMPONENT IM TRIGGERING THE $EVENT FROM

import Event from './vue-event.js';

export default Vue.component('app-buttons', {
 template: `
  <div class="postswrapper flex flex--center flex--column">

   <section :class="className" class="flex flex--center">
    <button type="button" @click="showUnpublished">Unpublish</button>
    <button type="button" @click="shufflePosts">Shuffle</button>
   </section>

   <section :class="className">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" v-on:input="updateValue" placeholder="Search..." />
   </section>

  </div>
 `,

 data() {
  return {
   className: 'buttons',
   search: '',
  }
 },

 props: {
  posts: Array,
 },

 created() {
  //console.log(this);
  console.log('%c Buttons', 'font-weight: bold;color:blue;', 'created');
 },

 methods: {
  updateValue() {
   //console.log(this.search);
   this.$emit('searchquery', this.search);
  },

  showUnpublished() {
   this.posts.forEach(item => {
    item.published = true;
   })
  },
 
  shufflePosts() {
   this.$emit('postshuffled', 'Fisher-Yates to the rescue');
   for (var i = this.posts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    let temp = this.posts[i];
    
    Vue.set(this.posts, i, this.posts[random]);
    Vue.set(this.posts, random, temp);
   }
  },
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Vue JS</title>
 
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div id="app">
  <app-header :logo="logo" :name="name"></app-header>
  <post-item :posts="posts" v-on:searchquery="update" v-on:sq="update" v-on:postshuffled="update"></post-item>
 </div>

 <script type="module">
  import AppHeader from './components/app-header.js';
  import PostItem from './components/post-item.js';

  const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
    name: 'Vue App',
    logo: {
     class: 'vue-logo',
     src: 'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png',
    },
    components: {
     AppHeader,
     PostItem,
    },
    posts: [
     {id: 1, title: 'Test', published: true},
     {id: 2, title: 'New post', published: true},
     {id: 3, title: 'Added', published: true},
     {id: 4, title: 'Another post', published: true},
     {id: 5, title: 'In the future', published: false},
     {id: 6, title: 'Last post', published: true},
    ],
   },

   created() {
    console.log('Created');
   },

   mounted() {
    console.log('Mounted');
   },

   methods: {
    update() {
     console.log('updated');
    }
   },
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are listening for the `searchquery` event on `post-item`, but you `$emit` in `app-buttons`. Vue events don't bubble.

Comment: Isn't that the entire idea behind $emit, that you can parse it to parent items?
- I Understood it as props is for children to inherit, and emit is to parse data back to parent.

Comment: Again, you're listening for the event on a component that is not emitting it. `app-buttons` emits. The parent is listening on `post-item`.

Comment: How would you then manage to listen to something from child components, and use that on the parents?

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> I have a child component "app-buttons", where i have an input field, i
>   want to listen to, so i can filter a list based on the input value.

You have:

```
<div id="app">
    <app-header :logo="logo" :name="name"></app-header>
    <post-item :posts="posts" v-on:searchquery="update" v-on:sq="update" v-on:postshuffled="update"></post-item>
</div>
```

That says you expect `post-item` to emit a `searchquery` event. It does not.

Within `post-item`, you have:

```
    <app-buttons :posts="posts"></app-buttons>
```

So you expect `app-buttons` to emit an event and `post-item` to implicitly bubble it up, but Vue events do not bubble. If you want that behavior, you will need to have `post-item` handle the event:

```
    <app-buttons :posts="posts" v-on:searchquery="$emit('searchquery', $event)"></app-buttons>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I see where i've misunderstood the $emit. Thanks for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've changed the markup, and it works. But would this be the best way to do it? :)
And thanks to **Roy J** for helping out.

```js
import Event from './vue-event.js';
import Buttons from './app-buttons.js';

export default Vue.component('post-item', {

 template: `
  <section class="posts flex" v-if="posts">
   <app-buttons :posts="posts" v-on:searchquery="update($event)"></app-buttons>

   <transition-group name="posts" tag="section" class="posts flex">
    <article class="postitem" :class="{ 'danger': !post.published }" v-for="post in filteredItems" :key="post.id">
     <p v-if="post.published">Post is published</p>
     <p v-else>Post is <em><strong>not</strong></em> published</p>
     <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>

     <button type="submit" @click="post.published = !post.published">Change status</button>
    </article>
   </transition-group>
  </section>
 `,

 data() {
  return {
   search: '',
  };
 },

 components: {
  Buttons,
 },

 props: {
  posts: Array,
 },

 created() {
  console.log('%c Post items', 'font-weight: bold;color:blue;', 'created');
 },

 computed: {
  filteredItems(search) {
   return this.posts.filter(post => {
    return post.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
   });
  }
 },

 methods: {
  update(event) {
   this.search = event;
  }
 }
});



// Child component
import Event from './vue-event.js';

export default Vue.component('app-buttons', {
 template: `
  <div class="postswrapper flex flex--center flex--column">

   <section :class="className" class="flex flex--center">
    <button type="button" @click="showUnpublished">Unpublish</button>
    <button type="button" @click="shufflePosts">Shuffle</button>
   </section>

   <section :class="className">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" v-on:input="updateValue" placeholder="Search..." />
   </section>

  </div>
 `,

 data() {
  return {
   className: 'buttons',
   search: '',
  }
 },

 props: {
  posts: Array,
 },

 created() {
  console.log('%c Buttons', 'font-weight: bold;color:blue;', 'created');
 },

 methods: {
  updateValue() {
   this.$emit('searchquery', this.search);
  },

  showUnpublished() {
   this.posts.forEach(item => {
    item.published = true;
   })
  },
 
  shufflePosts() {
   for (var i = this.posts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    let temp = this.posts[i];
    
    Vue.set(this.posts, i, this.posts[random]);
    Vue.set(this.posts, random, temp);
   }
  },
 }
});
```

```html
Index same as before, just without alle the events on the components.
```